# export 'default' (reexported as 'Navbar') was not found in './Navbar/Navbar'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error persists , I don't know how to solve it because im new to React. I tried some answers on stack overflow but they don't seem to work, maybe I lack the knowledge to see what is causing the error.

**Here is the code that's causing the error:**

```
export { default as Navbar} from './Navbar/Navbar';
export { default as Products} from './Products/Product';
```

**Here is the Navbar.jsx code:**

```
import React  from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton, Badge, MenuItem, Menu, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';
import logo from '../../assets/logo.jpg';


import useStyles from './styles';

const Navbar=() => {
    const classes = useSyles();
  return (
   <>
  <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} color="inherit">
    <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title} color="inherit">
            <img src={logo} alt="Commerce.js" height="25px" className={classes.image} />
              Commerce.js
           </Typography>

        <div className={classes.grow} />

            <div className={classes.button}>
              <iconButton aria-label="Show cart items" color="inherit" >

              </iconButton>
              <Badge badgeContent={2} color="secondary" >

                <ShoppingCart/>
              </Badge>

              </div>
      </Toolbar>

      </AppBar>

</>

)


}
```

**Here is how it looks inside Visual Code:**
[Inside Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFux2.png)

Comment: `Navbar` is not being exported?

Answer (score 0):

change `const Navbar=() => {`

to
`export default const Navbar=() => {`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing exporting those components as default.
Please add

export default Navbar   to the Navbar.js file.
export default Products to the Products.js file.

Comment: After i added that to Navbar this error appeared:

Comment: src\components\Navbar\Navbar.jsx
  Line 8:16:  'Navbar' is not defined    no-undef      
  Line 9:21:  'useSyles' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Did you expert useStyles as default from styles.js?

Comment: yes I did. export default makeStyles(() => ({

Comment: it should be a function that have a return value. like

export default () => makeStyles (()=>{...

if you are still getting something wrong, please let me know your anydesk id, then I can fix the issue.

Comment: import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    // maxWidth: 345, original width style
    maxWidth: '100%',
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  cardActions: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  cardContent: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
}));